# Azure text-to-voice: how can I change language and voice for output?

Tags: javascript, azure, text-to-speech, voice

I need help for the following JavaScript and hope someone can kindly help me. Text is read out in an English voice.

How can I change language and voice within the following working code? I intensively searched the web but couldn't find a suitable solution due to my poor java skills.

So, unfortunately my programming skills are not good enough, so I need some assistance for a concrete line of code. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  
  <button id="startSpeakTextAsyncButton">speak</button>
  
  <!-- Speech SDK reference sdk. -->
  <script src="microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"></script>

  <!--   Speech SDK Authorization token  -->
  <script>
  var authorizationEndpoint = "token.php";

  function RequestAuthorizationToken() {
    if (authorizationEndpoint) {
      var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
      a.open("GET", authorizationEndpoint);
      a.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      a.send("");
      a.onload = function() {
        var token = JSON.parse(atob(this.responseText.split(".")[1]));
        serviceRegion.value = token.region;
        authorizationToken = this.responseText;
        subscriptionKey.disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }
  </script>

  <!-- Speech SDK USAGE -->
  <script>
    var startSpeakTextAsyncButton;
    var serviceRegion = "westeurope"; 
    // for testing:
    // var voiceName = "HeddaRUS";
    // var voiceLanguage ="de-DE";

    var subscriptionKey;
    var authorizationToken;
    var SpeechSDK;
    var synthesizer;    

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      startSpeakTextAsyncButton = document.getElementById("startSpeakTextAsyncButton");
      subscriptionKey = document.getElementById("subscriptionKey");
      
        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = true;
        
        speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromAuthorizationToken(authorizationToken, serviceRegion);  
            
        // I don't know how the code should looke like:
        // speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.setSpeechSynthesisLanguage(voiceLanguage);
        // speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.setSpeechSynthesisVoiceName(voiceName);
            
        synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);

        // output should be in German language:    
        let inputText = "Ich möchte es auf deutsche Sprache setzen, weiß aber nicht wie!";
                
        synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
          inputText,
          function (result) {
            startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
            window.console.log(result);
            synthesizer.close();
            synthesizer = undefined;
          });
      });

      if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {
        SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;
        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
        if (typeof RequestAuthorizationToken === "function") {RequestAuthorizationToken();}
      }
    });
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a quick test, you can specify your language and voice in `speechConfig` as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  
  <button id="startSpeakTextAsyncButton" onclick="synthesizeSpeech()">speak</button>
  
  <!-- Speech SDK reference sdk. -->
  <script src="microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"></script>
 
  <script>
    function synthesizeSpeech() {
        
        var speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("<your subscription key,you can find it on azure portal=> Kesy and Endpoints blade>", "<your region>");
        speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (de-DE, Hedda)";
        speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = "de-DE";
        
        
        var synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);
        let inputText = "Ich möchte es auf deutsche Sprache setzen, weiß aber nicht wie!";
                
        synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
          inputText,
          function (result) {
            startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
            window.console.log(result);
            synthesizer.close();
            synthesizer = undefined;
        });
    }
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find all voice names on [this page](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/index.html#L130) from Line 130. It is not your fault,seems there is no official js sample for this :(

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right, there is neither an official nor an unofficial sample to fin in the net.

Yesterday I found by trying the short Version:
speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "de-DE-KatjaNeural";

It works well.

Unfortunately it seems not to be possible to place markups like 
<break time="100ms" /> 
direktly in the text to speak.

Comment: @kairo, welcome! If it is helful for you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer so that it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

The function to save the given text as an `mp3` file, feel free to use!

```js
const textToSpeech = async (key, region, text, filename)=> {
    // convert callback function to promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(key, region);
        speechConfig.speechSynthesisOutputFormat = 5; // mp3
   
        speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "es-MX-LibertoNeural";
        speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = "es-ES";

        let audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(filename);

        const synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
            text,
            result => {
                const { audioData } = result;

                synthesizer.close();

                // return stream from file
                const audioFile = fs.createReadStream(filename);
                resolve(audioFile);                
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                synthesizer.close();
                reject(error);
            });
    });
};

module.exports = {
    textToSpeech
};

// example of use - saves the generated audio in the oof3.mp3 file
(async () => {
    await textToSpeech('yourkeygoeshere', 'youregiongoeshere', 'El gato y el perro', 'oof3.mp3');
})();
```

**PS**

```
speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "es-MX-LibertoNeural";
```

is enough to make the output Spanish. Adding

```
speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = "es-ES";
```

doesn't change the output.

When you only set

```
speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = "es-ES";
```

the output is Spanish, but the voice is different (some default voice, I assume)

Voices are here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/js/browser/index.html#L130

To get more voices, execute these commands:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://YOUR_RESOURCE_REGION.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/voices/list' \
--header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_RESOURCE_KEY' > voices.txt
vim voices.txt
```

(taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech?tabs=streaming#get-a-list-of-voices)