# Azure Text to Speech (Cognitive Services) in web app - how to stop it from outputting audio?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure Cognitive Services for Text to Speech in a web app.

I return the bytes to the browser and it works great, however on the server (or local machine) the **speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inp)** line outputs the audio to the speaker.

Is there a way to turn this off, since this runs on a web server (and even if I ignore it, there's the delay while it outputs audio before sending back the data)

Here's my code ...

```
            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);

            speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "fa-IR-FaridNeural";
            speechConfig.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed;

            using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig))
            {
                // todo - how to disable it saying it here?
                var speechSynthesisResult = await speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inp);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(speechSynthesisResult.AudioData);
            }
```

Comment: `SpeechSynthesisVoiceName` should be `speechSynthesisVoiceName`, lowercase first letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What you can do is add an `audioconfig` to the `speechSynthesizer`.
- In this `audioconfig`  object you can specify a file path to a `.wav` file which already exist on the server.
- Whenever you run `speaktextasyn`  instead of a speaker it will redirect the data to the .wav file.
- This audio file you can read and perform your logic later.
- Just add the following code before creating the `speechSynthesizer`  object.

```
 var audioconfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput(filepath);
```

here `filepath` is a location of the `.wav` file as a string.

Complete code :

```
string filepath = "<file path> " ; 
var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion); 
var audioconfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput(filepath);


            speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "fa-IR-FaridNeural";
            speechConfig.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed;

            using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioconfig))
            {
                // todo - how to disable it saying it here?
                var speechSynthesisResult = await speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(inp);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(speechSynthesisResult.AudioData);
            }
```

Comment: Hi Mohit, thank you for your answer ... I tried the complete code (added var audioconfig ...) however this still didn't work.

I don't see where the variable audioconfig is used in your code however, is there a missing line?

Comment: Hi again Mohit, this worked! the only thing that was missing from your completed code is passing audioconfig into the SpeechSynthesizer contstructor (I edited the post to add this)

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75914130/4759176